# Site-to-Site VPN - Subnet Routing

Tags: site-to-site-vpn

Our HQ holds most subnets within 192.168.0.0/16.
Our branch office holds 192.168.1.0/24.

If i were to create a vpn tunnel, would it work if i set up the branch office router with "192.168.0.0/16" as remote network? Even though I am within that range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not very specific. What do you use, what is your setup.

Regarding routing tables. - Yes you can have more specific routes.
So you can say everything that goes into 192.168.0.0/16 goes to interface A, everything that goes to 192.168.0.0/24 goes to interface B and everything that goes to 192.168.0.0/30 goes to interface C. 
How you configure that on your router I have no idea as it depends on the system.